# jquery 2.0 jquery ui datepicker bug - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, each

Since I've switched to JQuery 2.0 got a bug with destroying jQuery UI (1.10.2) Datepickers.

Seems like the problem in modification of jquery.each() function.

I do following

```
$(this.el_picker).datepicker('destroy');
```

it calls in JQuery UI **line 9605**

```
return this.each(function() {
    typeof options === "string" ?
        $.datepicker["_" + options + "Datepicker"].
            apply($.datepicker, [this].concat(otherArgs)) :
        $.datepicker._attachDatepicker(this, options);
});
```

Then it calls following in **Jquery.each()** function:

```
if ( isArray ) {
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                if ( value === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the difference with older version of JQuery

```
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then it goes to JQuery UI **line 7922**

```
_destroyDatepicker: function(target) {
    var nodeName,
        $target = $(target),
        inst = $.data(target, PROP_NAME);

    if (!$target.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
        return;
    }

    nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    $.removeData(target, PROP_NAME);
    if (nodeName === "input") {
        inst.append.remove();
```

And throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined

Any ideas? Is it compatibility bug? How to fix it? Or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 13):

One way that I've found to fix this problem, assuming you want to reset the datepicker is:

```
 $(".hasDatepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker");
 $(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
 $(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you are calling destroy on a input which has the class, but does not have a datepicker() called on it yet.  For example:

```
..input class="dp" />
```

If you haven't yet called `$(".dp").datepicker()` and try to call `$(".dp").datepicker("destroy")` you will get this error. This also happens when you are dynamically adding rows where one of the row fields is a datepicker input. In this case the code sequence should be:

```
$(".dp").datepicker("destroy");
// code to add row dynamically
.....
$(".dp").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but I removed the destroy function and got it working. Not exactly like your example, but this was gleamed from: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NAgNV/)

and removed the knoukout cleanup to get this solution:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var $el = $(element);

                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = { minDate: 0
                        };
                $el.datepicker(options);

                //handle the field changing
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
                });

            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                    $el = $(element),
                    current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

                if (value - current !== 0) {
                    $el.datepicker("setDate", value);   
                }
            }
        };
```

I think the problem is that jquery shouldn't be forced to destroy the datepicker, when i removed this, i can refresh the page without the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined
```

error

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and I found another solution that mentioned adding the following script reference right below the jquery and jqueryui references:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

This worked for my problem with datepicker.